# how to store custom object with list in sqlite database in android

Tags: android, database, sqlite, database-design

how to create  table for a custom object that contain a list of like this

```
public class Mobel implements Parcelable {
    int thumbnail;
    List<Integer> pics;
    int price;
    String joziat;
    String code;
}
```

as you know there is no problem with int and string columns but how should i store my list of integer ? i was thinking to make a separate table for it but as i don't know ho many pic i have for particular object have no idea how should i join them

Answer (score 10, accepted):

While indeed you can not store objects in sqlite, you can serialize it and store the serialized object:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
String toStoreObject = gson.toJson(modelObject, Model.class);
```

And when you get the string back just do:

```
Model modelObject = gson.fromJson(storedObjectString, Model.class);
```

Or just serialize the property of the object (in your case the List).

Different things I would do:

1. Create another table for the images and link that table to the table in which you store your Model object (n to 1 relationship)
2. Don't store images in sqlite. Store them in the internal storage and in sqlite save just the path to the file.
3. If you really really want to store the images in sqlite, convert the image to a base64 string and store that one.

Comment: ty man ! but how can i convert a list of integer to json and later convert that json  to a list of integer ?

Comment: To get the serialized list as a String: String serializedList = gson.toJson(pics);

To get the list from a serialized string: 
Type type = new TypeToken<List<Integer>>() {}.getType();
List<Integer> pics = gson.fromJson(serializedList, type);

Comment: again thanks man . your anser really helped me , sry i cant give you +1