# What is the ideal way to store customized objects

Tags: java, android, sqlite, object

in my app I have two main kinds of objects: User & Company.
Both of them contain other custom object such as:
1. User - Interests / Profession
2. Company - Product

What would be the ideal method to store those objects in a database that I can easily manage and manipulate, e.g insert, remove and update actions.
I read about it in [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42432819/how-to-store-custom-object-with-list-in-sqlite-database-in-android?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Though it doesn't speaks about when you have object which contain other object or list of objects.
Is there any other good way beside SQLite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create Parent child relational table structure like :

1. User (Parent)
   a.Interests (Child of User mapped using user_id,interest_id)
   b.Profession (Child of User mapped using user_id,profession_id)
2. Company (Parent)
   a.Product(Child of Company mapped using company_id,product_id)

Comment: If you find this answer useful do mind to upvote as well!